# Entity Framework - Checking for duplicate values prior to updating the record

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Could you please assist me?  I am trying to update a Customer table in my database using Entity Framework (Front end calls my end point in the API to update record).  Before updating the record, I need to do some validations (such as making sure that a duplicate email address is not created on the database for the customer).

Below is my current code:

> if (await DuplicateEmailAddress(learnerEdit.EmailAddress)) return
> BadRequest("The email address is already being used for another learner.");

My method to check for duplicates:

> private async Task DuplicateEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
> {
> return await _context.Learners.AnyAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
> }

When I test my API call using Postman, I get the error message because the query is testing on the record I am updating as well.  Is there a way to exclude the record that I am updating when doing the validation?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your needs, it might be a better idea to enforce uniqueness on the database with some form of unique constraint on the email column (global unique mail) or on the compound (customerId, emailAddress) if the email should only be unique within the customer account. Trying to enforce uniqueness inside EF without database support is a solution waiting for race conditions to appear

Comment: Can you try: `_context.Learners.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);`

Comment: My suggestion is to read about designs pattern in this area. Example chain of responsibility or specification pattern.
 This can also improve the quality of the code

Comment: @grek40 Thank you for the useful insight.  I definitely want email addresses to be unique across the database.  However, I need to give this a little more thought because I have scenarios where a customer can be a supplier as well, so I need to be able to save him as both.  A bit of database design to consider.  Thank you

Comment: @klekmek Your recommendation worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @MasoudSharifi Thank you for your insight.  I will definitely investigate this further during the week.  I am still new at development.  But want to pursue it more professionally now.

Answer (score 2):

For an EF side check, you should modify your condition to exclude the entry you want to edit. Something like

```
_context.Learners.AnyAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress && x.Id != learnerEdit.Id);
```

As commended, you should additionally add a unique constraint to the database. Otherwise your code is open to race conditions, where your DB is ok when you check but already contains a duplicate when you `SaveChanges`

Comment: Thanks @Grek40.  I found that the AsNoTracking option has worked thus far.  I tried your method but, being new to development, I wasn't quite sure where you got the value of learnerEdit from.

Comment: @Jeremiah you would have to pass `learnerEdit` and not just `learnerEdit.EmailAddress` as parameter into your duplicate-check function.